# How to load array from php file using codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, file, codeigniter

I have a lot data in array, but I was not insert into database, is possible save they in a php file, and load it when for use?

example:

```
$myArray = fileContent;
```

my file `myFile.php`

```
array(
    array( [ 'id' ] => 12, [ 'nome' ] => "Acre", [ 'sigla' ] => "AC" ),
    array( [ 'id' ] => 27, [ 'nome' ] => "Alagoas", [ 'sigla' ] => "AL" ),
    array( [ 'id' ] => 16, [ 'nome' ] => "Amapa", [ 'sigla' ] => "AP" ),
    array( [ 'id' ] => 13, [ 'nome' ] => "Amazonas", [ 'sigla' ] => "AM" ),
    array( [ 'id' ] => 29, [ 'nome' ] => "Bahia", [ 'sigla' ] => "BA" ),
    // and more...
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it would be to create a file like this (call it "data.php"):

```
<?php

return array(
    array( [ 'id' ] => 12, [ 'nome' ] => "Acre", [ 'sigla' ] => "AC" ),
    array( [ 'id' ] => 27, [ 'nome' ] => "Alagoas", [ 'sigla' ] => "AL" ),
    array( [ 'id' ] => 16, [ 'nome' ] => "Amapa", [ 'sigla' ] => "AP" ),
    array( [ 'id' ] => 13, [ 'nome' ] => "Amazonas", [ 'sigla' ] => "AM" ),
    array( [ 'id' ] => 29, [ 'nome' ] => "Bahia", [ 'sigla' ] => "BA" ),
    // and more...
);
```

Then load it with

```
$data = require("/path/to/data.php");
```

Comment: this code is return a error: 
Message: require(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server 
configuration by allow_url_include=0

Comment: Notice that the path I listed is a path on the local file system. If you're trying to load it via HTTP, this method probably will not work (since the remote HTTP server is going to try to execute the file before serving anything).

Answer (score 1):

If it's static content, you can just load it in the controller action.

e.g.

```
public function index()
{
    $data['title'] = 'Page Title';
    $data['metaDesc'] = 'meta tags';
    $data['metaKeywords'] = '';                         
    $this->load->view('articles/view', $data);
}

<?php echo $title; ?>
```

Comment: I detailed my questions, how to can I load file content in controller?  I tried put this file in application/libraries/myFile.php and load it using $this->load->library("myFile"), but it's not work